# Oracle 9: Convert date from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format to iso8601 formatted datetime

Tags: oracle

Note: I only have read access to this database.

I need to convert an Oracle 9 date type from d/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format to the iso8601 standard. Like the example below:

`4/22/2015 12:02:56 AM => 2015-04-22T04:02:56.000Z`

Below is a a query that will convert an Oracle date type to a iso8601-formatted string. I need an is8601 formatted date.

```
SELECT sysdate,
    to_char((from_tz(to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') ,'America/New_York') at time zone 'UTC'),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"') "iso8601"
FROM dual
```

Thanks for any and all help.

---

**EDIT**: The end goal is to grab these dates and insert them as datetimes into a postgres database that powers a rails app.

Comment: So you have a character string (that represents a datetime in 'd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss'-format) that  you want to transform  in another character string (that represents the same datetime in the iso8601 format)?

Comment: The column is the datetime type. I want to transform it it into iso8601 formatted datetime so I can insert it into a postgres database.

Comment: I don't understand datetime type. I know DATE, TIMESTAMP , INTERVAL [data types](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i54330). In this manual Oracle uses 'datetime' for a DATE or one of the TIMESTAMP data types , but there is not somethings like a DATETIME data type. if you have a column of DATE or TIMESTAMP data type, then they dont have a format. So what kind of data type does your source have?

Comment: The string '4/22/2015 12:02:56 AM' does not represent a datetime in the 'd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' format. Ther is no month represented by 22.

Comment: @miracle173 My bad. Fixed the typos. They are Oracle date types I'm trying to convert into an iso8601 format.

Comment: ok, then you want to convert them in strings that represents the date in an iso8601 format. this strings you send to your postgres session that will transform them to the appropriate  postgres datetime data type. So you can use one of the given  answers?

Comment: if you do a  'select COLNAME from TABLENAME' on  the DATE column COLNAME of table TABLENAME an this returns values like '4/22/2015 12:02:56 AM' this does not mean that there are DATE values of this format stored in the table but that your default conversion for the  DATE data type to the string data type in your session is 'm/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'. It does not mean that they are stored in this format.

Comment: both Oracle and PostgreSQL have a DATE and TIMESTAMP data types. But you cannot read it directly in an Oracle session and write it in a PostgreSQL session. Because there internal representation of this data is [completely different](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html). You have to convert it to a string when reading it in the Oracle session and [convert it from a string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html) when writing in the postgres session.

Comment: Do you just want to set the **output** format or convert your times to UTC time zone?

Answer (score 10):

You should use `SYSTIMESTAMP` instead of `SYSDATE`, in order to get fractional seconds (which you desire as I assume).

`SYSTIMESTAMP` returns data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, thus you don't have to specify explicitly.

So it is:

```sql
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(
        SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
        'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"'
    )
FROM dual
```

Comment: Isn't this casting to a string? I need it casted to a datetime.

Comment: Note that I got an error when I included .ff3 

`ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
*Cause:    
*Action:`

Comment: @Matthew, what is the command you use? The command in my answer will **never** raise such an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"';

Session altered.

SQL> select cast (sysdate as timestamp) from dual;

CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-07-18T01:26:09.000Z
```

Comment: This is only correct when you local time zone is UTC! Note, if the user changes his local time zone then the display is still `....Z` - which is wrong. Time zone independent format is `'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3TZH:TZM'`